# Use Cookie for cross site tracking example

Tags: cookies

I am trying to understand how using cookie for cross site tracking actually works after reading some articles through the internet.

Here is my understanding through an example:

Imagine `shoe.com` integrates a 3rd party tracking service `tracking.com` through `<script>` tag. When Peter visits `shoe.com`, behind the scene the script will run and issue a request to `tracking.com`, the response returned from `tracking.com` will instruct the browser to set a cookie, let's say, `uid=1234-5678`. The reason `tracking.com` wants to set this cookies is because it wants to identify Peter (`1234`) and the site he visits (`5678`) with a value.

Later Peter visits `social.com`, which also integrates `tracking.com`. Again, behind the scene, the script will run and issue a request to `tracking.com` with the cookie `uid=1234-5678`. The request can bring this cookie to `tracking.com` server is because it is set by `tracking.com` previously. `tracking.com` server receives the cookie, knows this person (Peter) once visited `shoe.com`, then shows a shoe ad on the page.

Is my understanding correct? Any area of the above example can be improved to reflect the actual mechanism? I have tried to gather useful information on internet but most of the articles don't deep dive to explain the concept. It would be great if some links regarding to this subject can be provided, thanks.